# Wrong Position after Filtering and on Click in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have Implemented SearchView in my App. But the Problem I am facing is the recycler view returns the wrong position after filtering. How can i get the exact position after filtering.

Here is my code of Adapter:-

```
public class UserListAdapter extends Adapter<UserListAdapter.DataObjectHolder> implements Filterable {
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
public Activity activity;
Bitmap bitmap;
ImageView imgUserBig;
TextView txtUserName;
RelativeLayout userProfileView;
private ArrayList<DataObject> mArrayList;
private ArrayList<DataObject> mFilteredList;    

public UserListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<DataObject> d, ImageView mImgUserBig, RelativeLayout viewLinear, TextView txtUsername) {

    this.activity = a;
    this.mArrayList = d;
    this.mFilteredList = d;
    this.imgUserBig = mImgUserBig;
    this.userProfileView = viewLinear;
    this.txtUserName = txtUsername;
}

public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new DataObjectHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw_user_list, parent, false));
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.txtName.setText((mFilteredList.get(position)).getmName());
    holder.txtUserName.setText((mFilteredList.get(position)).getmUsername());
    Glide.with(activity.getApplicationContext()).load((mFilteredList.get(position)).getmImage()).into(holder.imgUser);
    Glide.with(activity).load((mFilteredList.get(position)).getmImage()).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
            bitmap = resource;
            (mFilteredList.get(position)).setBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
    holder.imgUser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if ((mFilteredList.get(position)).getBitmap() != null && imgUserBig != null) {
                zoomImageFromThumb(holder.imgUser, (mFilteredList.get(position)).getBitmap(), (mFilteredList.get(position)).getmImage(), (mFilteredList.get(position)).getmUsername());
            }
        }
    });
}

public int getItemCount() {
    return mFilteredList.size();
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    UserListAdapter.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                mFilteredList = mArrayList;
            }else {
                ArrayList<DataObject> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataObject userData : mArrayList) {
                    if (userData.getmUsername().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || userData.getmName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                        filteredList.add(userData);
                    }
                }
                mFilteredList = filteredList;
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mFilteredList = (ArrayList<DataObject>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public interface MyClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int i, View view);
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mFilteredList.get(position);
}



public class DataObjectHolder extends ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {
    ImageView imgUser;
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtUserName;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        txtUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
        imgUser = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_user);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        UserListAdapter.myClickListener.onItemClick(getPosition(), v);
    }
}}
```

I am calling getPosition() Method to get the position of the item, but it returns the old position, not the filtered one. Any Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class to implement the scroll listener before recyclerview reaches to its end . It notify when 5 items are left to be scrolled . See Code below.

Just put it in your projectas a separate class

```
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;


public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
{
    public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();
private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

private int current_page = 0;

private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManagerG;

public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager)
{
    this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}


public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager)
{
    this.mLinearLayoutManagerG = linearLayoutManager;
    mLinearLayoutManager = null;
}


public void reset()
{
    current_page = 0;
    previousTotal = 0;
    loading = true;
}

public void setThresHold(int threshold)
{
    visibleThreshold = threshold;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
{
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    if (mLinearLayoutManager != null)
    {
        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(null)[0];

        if (loading)
        {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal)
            {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))
        {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            current_page++;

            onLoadMore(current_page);

            loading = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManagerG.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManagerG.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading)
        {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal)
            {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))
        {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            current_page++;

            onLoadMore(current_page);

            loading = true;
        }

    }

    countChange(firstVisibleItem);
}

public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);

public abstract void countChange(int currentVisibleCount);
}
```

Use it like this

```
endlessRecyclerOnScrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(pass your layout manager here)
    {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            pageNumber++;
            // Hit your api for more records 
        }

        @Override
        public void countChange(int currentVisibleCount) {

        }
    };

    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(endlessRecyclerOnScrollListener);
```

There is a variable named `current_page` , By default it starts from 0 , you can change it according to your api. `visibleThreshold` says that before how many items your `onLoadMore` method should be called .

Example: If the `visibleThreshold` is 5 and total data in the list is 20, then `onLoadMore` will be called when your recyclerview is scrolled upto 15th position.

Let me know if you have more queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use getAdapterPosition() in your onClick method because then at the time of the click u want to know the position of the item. If u check at the time of the creation it will (most of the times) be inaccurate